# make canvas fullscreen in safari mobile browser ios 7

Tags: jquery, canvas, meta-tags, ios7.1

heelo guys, i have been trying to adjust some code template of a canvas game . it runs fine on android but the canvas doesnt show fully but its trimmed off in the ios7 safari browser.

this is my canvas html ;

```
<div id="c2canvasdiv">
    <canvas id="c2canvas" width="800" height="600">
    </canvas>
```

i used these usual meatatags .

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

and

```
// Size the canvas to fill the browser viewport.
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        cr_sizeCanvas(jQuery(window).width(), jQuery(window).height());
    });
```

but still the canvas doesn't show fully in ios7.

any body knows any alternative methods of achieving canvas full-screen in ios7 safari?

Answer (score 0):

you can leave the canvas width and height the same and just change the style width and height, and it will scale the canvas to the style.